# Locate user name after gear icon

Tags: 14.04, unity, indicator, panel

I want to ask something about customizing my Ubuntu panel.

Default panel for the Ubuntu is like this

[image]

'gear icon' is default at the left of the name, but i want to change it, i want to place 'gear icon' at the right of my name.

Is it possible?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?  Unity, GNOME, Xfce4?

Comment: it's unity .. the default DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unfortunately no settings option provided for that. There's only option to show and hide the name

```
$ gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.indicator.session
com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-menuitem false
com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-restart-menuitem true
com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-shutdown-menuitem false
com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown false
com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu true
```

Answer (score 0):

its so sad to hear that. Actually i made my own system icon with my name on this .. nice shortcut, thanks for help.

[My panel appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JErJT.png)